# How to calculate Internal Rate of Return (IRR) in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, irr

I try to calculate an **Internal Rate of Return (IRR)** in a **C# .NET Core 2.2** project.

Is there any built in formula that I could use?

From the MSDN documentation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.irr?view=netframework-4.8), you should be able to import the VisualBasic Namespace and its Financial Formulas into a .NET Framework Project.

But, trying to do so in a .NET Core Project, I don't get any useful method from the  Microsoft.VisualBasic package.

Any hint (apart from coding from scratch the whole algorithm) ?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko my question stated precisely **apart from coding the whole algorithm**. The link you provided gives the implementation of the algorithm (in VB!), so I need to convert it and re-implement it in C#... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bottom line is, as found by @cdev, **there is no built in formula unless you switch to .NET Core 3.0 Preview**.

But, as a workaround, I found a Nuget Package which wraps Excel Financial Functions Library : [ExcelFinancialFunctions from Luca Bolognese](http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelFinancialFunctions/) and contains an IRR Method.

Then, it becomes straightforward :

```
    private double ComputeIRR()
    {
        double[] cashFlows = new double[]{-1000,100,100,1200}; //should contain at least one negative and one positive value
        double irr = Financial.Irr(cashFlows);
        return irr;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, we do; with link. It'd be better to include how to use the library (with code) in yoru answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in formula unless you using [.NET Core 3.0 Preview 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.irr?view=netcore-3.0)

```
double[] values = new double[] { -70000, 22000, 25000, 28000, 31000 };

//// values[0] - Business start-up costs.
//// values[1-n] - Positive cash flows reflecting income for four successive years.

//// Guess starts at 10 percent.
double guess = 0.1;

double CalcRetRate = Financial.IRR(values, guess);
```

Comment: Hush, that's why. Thanks!

Comment: @cdev can you include how to use that API in your answer?